# How do I make modifications to the root window from a sub window in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I'm trying to make a sub-window which allows you to alter certain parameters within the main window. I created a function which, when called by a button, will pop up, have an option menu to choose which option you want to alter, then some entry boxes to enter in what you want to alter.

My first thought was to alter the data in the function then just return it, but I didn't think that would work since the function is being called at the touch of a button. Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: ***" I didn't think that would work"***: Why did you think so?

Comment: You are correct that a `return` wont work when called from a Tkinter Button. That said you don't need your function to return anything. You function can just modify the root window directly.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, I'm trying to ask _how_ to directly modify the root window. Would I just , in the code, do something akin to 

`def example(): \n
    this = that \n
    root.some_var = this`?

Comment: @stovfl, I didn't think it would bc it's called from a button so there isn't an appropriate variable to return to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple example of how one could update the root window directly and any variables in the global namespace. Its just a matter of what you do in the functions you call from you buttons.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.config(background='white')
root.geometry('250x100')

label_1 = tk.Label(root, text=0)
label_1.pack()
label_2 = tk.Label(root, text='test')
label_2.pack()


def toggle_root_bg():
    # check the color of the root window and toggle accordingly.
    if root['background'] == 'black':
        root.config(background='white')
    else:
        root.config(background='black')


def update_root_labels(one, two):
    # Apply argument values to the text fields of the labels defined in the global namespace.
    label_1.config(text=one)
    label_2.config(text=two)


def sub_window():
    # setting sub window variable name to be used with other widgets.
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Label(top, text='Provide a number: ').grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label(top, text='Provide a string: ').grid(row=1, column=0)
    entry_1 = tk.Entry(top)
    entry_2 = tk.Entry(top)
    entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    # create a sub function to get the current entry field values
    # then pass these values on to our update function.
    def submit_update():
        update_root_labels(entry_1.get(), entry_2.get())

    tk.Button(top, text='Update root labels', command=submit_update).grid(row=2, column=0)
    tk.Button(top, text='Toggle Root Background', command=toggle_root_bg).grid(row=3, column=0)


tk.Button(root, text='Open sub window', command=sub_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: One more thing, how would you apply this to editing a list variable?

Comment: @DanielMayper depends on what you want to do with that list. Probably `list_name.append()` to add values to a list in the global namespace. Or any other modifier.